# DOM InsertBefore in a foreach-loop

Tags: c#, html, dom

I'am using AngleSharp for parsing HTML.
Now I want to insert a `<BR>` before every image.
So I do the following:

```
var xx = document2.GetElementsByTagName("img");                
var document3 = parser.Parse(BodyCode);
var br = document3.CreateElement("BR");
foreach (var pic in xx)
   {
     document3.Body.AppendChild(pic);
     document3.Body.InsertBefore(br, pic);
   }
```

It should look like

```
<br><img></img><br><img></img><br><img></img>
```

But actualy it look like

```
<img></img><img></img><br><img></img>
```

If I debug this loop, I can see, that the **br** is created before every **img**, but not permanently.

```
1. <br><img></img>

2. <img></img><br><img></img>

3. <img></img><img></img><br><img></img>
```

Where is my mistake?
THX

Comment: Why not just do `document3.Body.AppendChild(br); document3.Body.AppendChild(pic);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only create one line break and just moving it with each iteration of the loop. Make a new one for each insert.

```
foreach (var pic in xx)
{
     var br = document3.CreateElement("BR");
     document3.Body.AppendChild(pic);
     document3.Body.InsertBefore(br, pic);
}
```